# Python Append from a list to another on a condition

Tags: python, list

i'm a python newbie and i want to check if a each list element is present in another list(while respecting the index) and append this element to a third list.  like this. if first element of 'listy'("11-02-jeej") contains first element of list_of_dates ("11-02), i want this element "11-02-jeej" to be appended in the first list of a list of lists. the code below doesn't work for me :(

```
the output that i want from this code is :[["11-02-jeej"], [2apples], []]
but instead i get : [[], [], []]
```

thank you so much !

```
list_of_dates =["11-02,", "2", "5"]
listy = ["11-02-jeej", "2apples", "d44"]
length = len(list_of_dates)
lst = [[] for m in range(length)]

for i in range(len(list_of_dates)):
    date =  list_of_dates[i]
    for j in range(len(listy)):
         name = listy [j]
    if date in name:
        lst[m].append(name)

print(lst)
```

Comment: You have a comma in the first string value ("11-02,"), so it is **not** a prefix of another string.

Comment: @trincot thank you so much! the code works now, however, what if i want it to look for that specific char/ string at any position in the list element; rather than the start like you added? "if name.startswith(date) "?

Comment: Then use `in` like you had it. I just thought that maybe you wanted only to check the start, as that looked like so in the example. But then just do the `in` as you had it. It was an optional thing to change. I removed that point now from my answer, and reinstated the `in` operator. Please comment below my answer, though, not here. However, realise that if you use `in`, then "2" will match with "11-02" too, not only with "2apples"!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are the following issues in your code:

- The input has a comma in the first string: "11-02,". As you expect this to be a prefix, I suppose that trailing comma should not be there: "11-02"
- The `if` statement should be *inside* the inner loop, since it needs the `name` variable that is assigned there.
- `m` is not the correct index. It should be `i`, so you get: `lst[i].append(name)`

So here is your code with those corrections:

```
list_of_dates =["11-02", "2", "5"]
listy = ["11-02-jeej", "2apples", "d44"]
length = len(list_of_dates)
lst = [[] for m in range(length)]

for i in range(len(list_of_dates)):
    date =  list_of_dates[i]
    for j in range(len(listy)):
        name = listy [j]
        if date in name:
            lst[i].append(name)

print(lst)
```

Note that these loops can be written with list comprehension:

```
lst = [[s for s in listy if prefix in s] for prefix in list_of_dates]
```

Be aware that for the given example, "2" also occurs in "11-02-jeej", so you have both "11-02" and "2" giving a match, and so that will impact the result. If you wanted "2" to only match with "2apples", then you may want to test a match only at the *start* of a string, using `.startswith()`.

Comment: Dear @trincot trailing comma is not causing any issue as the OP is using `in` property. I ran OP's code with a trailing comma and it runs fine. Please check.

Comment: @TalhaTayyab, your script includes it because of the "2" in the first list. The Asker however explained in their question that it should be included because of "11-02". Please check (e.g. what happens when you remove the "2" from the first list).

Comment: Shouldn't the list-comp be `lst = [[s for s in listy if s.startswith(prefix)] for prefix in list_of_dates]` to produce a nested list?